# Data is being displayed in the console, but doesn't in the UI Page

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I've created a React table, and I have a data in Elasticsearch. I have successfully fetched data from Elasticsearch using API(fetch) call; this data is being displayed in the console but not in screen. How to solve this problem?

this code will fetch data from Elasticsearch, then display it on React Table.

```js
import './App.css';
import Table from './pages/Table';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [dataTable, setDataTable] = useState([]);
  
    // this is our JOSN data to be displayed in the console
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic xxcxxxxxxxxx==");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var requestOptions = {
method: 'GET',
headers: myHeaders,
redirect: 'follow'
};


 // this is fetching data from Elastic and working successfully
 
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://192.168.1.3:9200/myapp/_doc/1", requestOptions)
.then(response => response.json())
 .then(result => setDataTable(result.data))   // the error comes here 
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}, []);
console.log(dataTable);

  const column = [
    { heading: 'Id', value: '_index' },
      { heading: 'Index', value: '_index' },
    { heading: 'Score', value: '_score' },
    { heading: 'Timestamp', value: '@timestamp' },
    { heading: 'Version', value: '@version' },

    { heading: 'Ephemeral Id', value: 'agent.ephemeral_id' },
    { heading: 'Agent Id', value: 'agent.id' },
    { heading: 'Agent name', value: 'agent.name' },
    { heading: 'Agent type', value: 'agent.type' },
    { heading: 'Agent Version', value: 'agent.version' },

    { heading: 'esc version', value: 'esc.version' },
    { heading: 'event original', value: 'event.original' },

    { heading: 'host architecture', value: 'host.architecture' },
    { heading: 'host hostname', value: 'host.hostname' },
    { heading: 'host id', value: 'host.id' },
    { heading: 'host ip', value: 'host.ip' },
    { heading: 'host mac', value: 'host.mac' },
    { heading: 'host name', value: 'host.name' },

    { heading: 'host os build', value: 'host.os.build' },
    { heading: 'host os family', value: 'host.os.family' },
    { heading: 'host os kernel', value: 'host.os.kernel' },
    { heading: 'host os name', value: 'host.os.name' },
    { heading: 'host os platform', value: 'host.os.platform' },
    { heading: 'host os type', value: 'host.os.type' },
    { heading: 'host os version', value: 'host.os.version' },

    { heading: 'input type', value: 'input.type' },
    { heading: 'log file path', value: 'log.file.path' },
    { heading: 'log offset', value: 'log.offset' },
    { heading: 'message', value: 'message' }, 
    { heading: 'tags', value: 'tags' },
    
  ]

  
//   console.log(column)
  return (
    <div className="App" >
       <h1>eSafe Table</h1>

      <Table data={dataTable} column={column} />
      
          
    </div>
  );
    }
export default App;
```

Comment: Can you show some code please ?

Comment: please provide some source code to go off of, or even better, a minimum reproducible sandbox.

Comment: If you are sure that your api is returning the date, the problem is not Elasticsearch. Maybe the problem is in handling the response in your javascript or react UI elements.

Comment: Okay, I have added "App.js" code which is the code that I used to fetch data from Elasticsearch

Comment: When you `console.log(result)` in `.then(result => setDataTable(result.data))`, what do you have ?

Comment: This error Occur 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

 at Table (Table.js:13:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
   
  "

Comment: but when I use "console.log(result)" instead of "setDataTable(result.data))" , it will display data in the console without error